# Unable apply styles for action bar in android material design with appcompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, material-design

Hi I am building small android application in which I tried to change color for action-bar but it is not working for me. I tried it in following way:

```
 // in values/themes.xml.
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#0097a7</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#0097a7</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#0097a7</item>

    <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item> -->
 </style>
```

I am using appcompat_7.But above styling is not working for me. Am I doing something wrong. Need some help.

Answer (score 1):

With the **appcompat v21**, you have to remove the `android: attribute`.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#0097a7</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#0097a7</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#0097a7</item>
 </style>
```

To use these styles you have to compile your project with API 21.

Comment: I tried that as well but it gives me error for those attributes like `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.`

Comment: I have to include appcompat v21? I am including one appcompat but I am not sure that one is same which you are talking about. Where can I get appcompt v21?

Comment: @nilkash yes. These styles work with API 21 and with Appcompat 21.
To get the updated appcompat, use you sdk manager and find it in your sdk folder.